# Socket.io express server not accessible on other devices

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

I have a simple `socket.io` and `expressjs` application running. They are hosting a simple HTML file. When I try to access this file in my browser, it works. But it seems to fail on other devices on my network.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
users = [];
connections = [];

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Server running...')

var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "")));
```

I feel like I'm missing something. 
What could I do to deploy this site to other devices (or the internet in general)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen on `.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");` and you have to open a port for it on the firewall.

Or You can use [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/), it will give you a secure URL to your localhost server through any NAT or firewall (local network, or global)